# Javassist Enhancement failed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss-tools

I use Jboss IDE as IDE. I have created a Hibernate project. and I get this error when deploying my .har (Hibernate project) :

```
16:16:30,910 ERROR [BasicLazyInitializer] Javassist Enhancement failed: com.afrikbrain.iard.srv.ref.AssGarantieProduit
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.findClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:623)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:467)
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:408)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.getMethods(ProxyFactory.java:743)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.getMethods(ProxyFactory.java:737)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.getMethods(ProxyFactory.java:730)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.make(ProxyFactory.java:547)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:333)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:312)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:271)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:138)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:42)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:295)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
 at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
 at org.jboss.hibernate.jmx.Hibernate.buildSessionFactory(Hibernate.java:231)
 at org.jboss.hibernate.jmx.Hibernate.startService(Hibernate.java:155)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
 at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
 at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
 at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
 at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
 at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
 at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
 at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
 at $Proxy10.deploy(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:610)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)
16:16:30,922 WARN  [PojoEntityTuplizer] could not create proxy factory for:com.afrikbrain.iard.srv.ref.AssGarantieProduit
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.afrikbrain.iard.srv.ref.AssGarantieProduit
 at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:145)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:42)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:295)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
 at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
 at org.jboss.hibernate.jmx.Hibernate.buildSessionFactory(Hibernate.java:231)
 at org.jboss.hibernate.jmx.Hibernate.startService(Hibernate.java:155)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
 at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
 at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
 at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
 at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
 at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
 at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
 at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
 at $Proxy10.deploy(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:610)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.findClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:623)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:467)
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:408)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.getMethods(ProxyFactory.java:743)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.getMethods(ProxyFactory.java:737)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.getMethods(ProxyFactory.java:730)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.make(ProxyFactory.java:547)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:333)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:312)
 at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:271)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:138)
 ... 58 more
16:16:31,059 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service AssurHibernate.har:service=Hibernate
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.findClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:623)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:467)
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:408)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getterMethod(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:317)
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetterOrNull(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:297)
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetterOrNull(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:304)
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:280)
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:275)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:168)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:44)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:123)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
 at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
 at org.jboss.hibernate.jmx.Hibernate.buildSessionFactory(Hibernate.java:231)
 at org.jboss.hibernate.jmx.Hibernate.startService(Hibernate.java:155)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
 at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
 at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
 at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
 at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
 at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
 at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
 at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
 at $Proxy10.deploy(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:610)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
 at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)
16:16:31,080 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get stack traces with this in it:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.findClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:623)
```

It usually means that JBoss's classloader has got itself into an unrecoverable state, and the loading of certain core classes fails, which occasionally happens after a lot of hot deployments.

In my experience, it is usually fixed by a JBoss restart.

Answer (score 2):

Check the list:

1. You must have default constructor with no-arg
2. Constructor must be **public**

Comment: My problem was that I had no default constructor with no-arg. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Good hint with PUBLIC default constructor. Without proxies Hibernate also accepts a private default constructor, but with proxies javaassist wants it public.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace is quite complex, you'd better ask to JBoss developers on the JBoss mailing lists/forums, or open a bug report (given that there is a java.lang.NullPointerException, it is surely a bug).

Anyway, given that the error is reported in:

```
org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.findClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:623)
```

it's a problem during class loading, while looking for some class.
You can either look at sources of org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader (line 623) to see if you find anything useful, or directly ask for support elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should be use this property in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
```

if there is no reason using javaassit.jar, should remove that jar file from project build path, that all can solve it easily since i have solved this way.

thank;
thihasoe